# JS - repeat action N times without a for or while loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

For example, I want to create some debug data array and I need a function that will take only the length of desired array and return array of objects with few props with random data values.

Is there a way to make this function without a for loop?
The reason for the question is that I have this `i` variable that I don't really need.

```
const generateData = (count) => {
  let data = []
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)  
    data.push({
      foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      bar: Math.random() > 0.5
    })
  return data  

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create the array all at once with `Array.from`, if you want, no declaration or usage of any intermediate variable names:

```js
const generateData = length => (
  Array.from(
    { length },
    () => ({
      foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      bar: Math.random() > 0.5
    })
  )
);
console.log(generateData(5));
```

Comment: I like that. Thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX OP didn't say without loops, he said without *for* loops.

Comment: Wait, `Array.from()` will work on an object with just a `length` property? I duno how I'd feel about using that, but it's pretty cool!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of pushing every iteration into a target array you can create at once the array of size you need and then map each item to a random initiated value the way you need.

```js
    function initArray(amount) {
        return [...new Array(amount)].map(() => ({
            foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
            bar: Math.random() > 0.5
        }));
    }
    console.log(initArray(5));
```

Actually this is still an iterating but with more functional approach.

Comment: Good code but it would be nice if you could add some explanation of what it's doing for those who come across it.

Comment: Why are you spreading (`...`) an new array into an array literal? Is there some thing I'm not aware of, or wouldn't `new Array(amount).map(...)` work just as well/better?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an array of `n` length and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to random objects.

```js
const createRandomArray = n => arr = [...Array(n)].map(() => ({
  foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
  bar: Math.random() > 0.5
}));

console.log(createRandomArray(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a recursive function:

```
const generateData = (count) => {
  let data = []
  function recursive(num) {
    if (num > 1) {
      num--;
      data.push({
        foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        bar: Math.random() > 0.5
      })
      recursive(num);
    }
    else {
      data.push({
        foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        bar: Math.random() > 0.5
      })
      return;
    }
  }
  recursive(count);
  return data  

}
```

Relatively large, but extremely simple to see what everything's doing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timer = null;
  const generateData = (count,cb) => {
     let data = [];
     var num = 0;
     timer = setInterval(function(){
       if(num>=count){
           clearInterval(timer);
           cb(data)
        }else{
          data.push({
             foo: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
             bar: Math.random() > 0.5
           })
           num++;
        }
     },10)
  }
  generateData(5,function(data){
   console.log(data)
  })
```